# WMSLayer not showing, ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, wms

I've started to dabble in the JavaScript API for ArcGIS and I am having an issue with a layer I want to display. It's this [WMS Layer](https://catalogue.data.gov.bc.ca/dataset/mta-mineral-placer-and-coal-tenure-spatial-view/resource/f020cabf-e958-4d83-b202-2dc625272688):

In the following code (mostly taken from the ESRI tutorial [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/intro_firstmap_amd.html)), I can create the basemap just fine, however the WMS layer doesn't populate. Given the WMSLayer [help document](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-WMSLayer.html) here, it appears that I can just declare a variable for a new WMSLayer and add the URL. That doesn't seem to work. I saw some suggests in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206412/why-is-this-wms-layer-not-showing-up-in-openlayers), about removing the 'request=GetCapabilities' portion of the URL and I've played around with a few other suggestions such as adding the layer to the map after I've declared it (`map.addLayer(layer)`), but nothing seems to populate. Given that I am fairly new with JavaScript, I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, when the map opens it is zoomed to an area around Hudson Hope BC. The WMS Layer should show show some hatched polygons North East of Hudson Hope along the North side of the #29 highway.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>Map</title>
<style>
  html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.27/esri/css/esri.css">
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.27/"></script>
<script>
  require([
          "esri/map",
          "dojo/domReady!",
          "esri/layers/WMSLayer"
          ],

          function (
                Map,
                WMSlayer
                ){

          var map = new Map("map", {
          basemap: "topo",
          center: [-121.40, 56.05],
          zoom: 10
          });

          // Typical usage
          var layer = new WMSLayer({url: "https://openmaps.gov.bc.ca/geo/pub/WHSE_MINERAL_TENURE.MTA_ACQUIRED_TENURE_SVW/ows?service=WMS"});
          })

</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```